# json response is null from jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

it's once again late at night and i'm banging my head against the wall.

I've got a jquery ajax call:

```
    function waitForMsg(){


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "backend.php",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 50000, /* Timeout in ms */
                    data: "TimeStamp=" + TimeStamp,
        success: function(data){

                        var json = eval('(' + data + ')');

                        $('#TextHistory :last-child').after('<p>' + json.message + '</p>');

          TimeStamp = json['timestamp'];

            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                5000            /* ..after 5 seconds */
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

            $('#TextHistory :last-child').after('<p>' + errorThrown + '</p>');

            setTimeout(
                'waitForMsg()', /* Try again after.. */
                "15000");       /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
        },
    });
};
```

which goes off to backend.php which currently looks like:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array();

$response["message"] = "Blarde Bar Blar";

$response["timestamp"] = $LastMsgUpdated;   // part of bigger script this is taken from.

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

...but when the ajax success function runs I get a message in firebug saying "json.msg is null"...and indeed when I look at the json object in the watch window it shows it as being null. I'm trying to learn this at the moment so not sure if I'm doing something fundermentally wrong, or if i've just missed something stupid. I've also noticed that there isn't any response headers in firebug. How can this be when their clearly there at the top of backend.php.....so strange, making my head hurt...need sleep.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` that is passed to the callback is already a JavaScript object as you set the `dataType` option to `json`:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

So this line creates garbage:

```
var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

*(I get an `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error in Chrome)*

Remove it and use `data.message`.

---

Apart from that, don't use `eval` to parse JSON data, [there are better methods available](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: hhhmm, well changing to 

       $('#TextHistory :last-child').after('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');


still gives a data is null message. Also the response headers still aren't being set. I've just tried absolutly specifying the url of backend.php just incase the backend script wasn't getting called and it didn't help.

Comment: @Dan Twining: Well, then there must be something wrong at the server side. Make it simple and just return some simple text and see if you can receive it.

Comment: Ok, well I removed the json = eval bit, changed it to data.message, and removed the Timestamp = json bit and it's worked! Thanks guys, hopefully I can get it going from here.

Comment: Well further developments....I've found that if i put any kind of php into my backend.php script, even something as simple as session_start() I get a data is null error. This is a bit of a pain because I wanted to build up the json response by querying my database!

Answer (score 0):

Your json is actualy called data at this point:

```
$('#TextHistory :last-child').after('<p>' + json.message +
```

This is due to:

```
function(data){
```

So you should access it like this:

```
$('#TextHistory :last-child').after('<p>' + data.message +
```

Comment: no, he turned it from a response string into an object with the eval line before that, and called it `json`

Comment: i see that now.  data.message would work better.  Is there some reason to eval?